# Kafka JDBC Sink Connector Not Consuming Events from Remote Cluster

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Standalone Kafka JDBC sink connector not inserting data into mysql database (Using confluent-community-2.12)

I've installed confluent-community-2.12 on centos7 and started the standalone jdbc sink connector to consume records from a remote kafka cluster. I can consume the records via a simple java consumer and see the record data  however, when I start the sink connector it loads and connects to the remote cluster fine but just stops at the following log INFO

```
[2019-05-01 11:10:21,619] INFO Initializing writer using SQL dialect: MySqlDatabaseDialect (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:57)

[2019-05-01 11:10:21,620] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-mysql-standalone-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:301)
```

Even after starting the connector if I produce any data to the cluster, at sink connector nothing happens.

I tried to fetch the result of the connector status using:

```
curl localhost:8083/connectors/sink-mysql-standalone/status
```

the result is as follows:

```
{"name":"sink-mysql-standalone","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.3.0.40:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.3.0.40:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
```

sink.properties:

```
name=sink-mysql-standalone
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=my-topic

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# JDBCSink connector specific configuration
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://10.3.0.37:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
connection.user=myuser
connection.password=mypassword
insert.mode=upsert
table.name.format = tbl_kaf_${topic}
pk.mode=kafka
pk.fields=__connect_topic,__connect_partition,__connect_offset
fields.whitelist=messageId
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
```

The producer produces following record:

```
Key: id_5dfbdffe-ffbc-4fbf-925c-a14734304fa8, Value: {
 "type" : "text",
 "messageId" : "ID:activemq-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-X:XX:1:2:2",
 "correlationId" : "",
 "destination" : {
  "type" : "queue",
  "name" : "qToKafka"
 },
 "replyTo" : null,
 "priority" : 0,
 "expiration" : 0,
 "timestamp" : 1556549819473,
 "redelivered" : false,
 "properties" : {},
 "payloadText" : "<Some XML Data>",
 "payloadMap" : null,
 "payloadBytes" : null
}
```

Please let me know what am I missing here. 
Thanks

Comment: Has the table been generated on MySQL or not?

Comment: Nope. I created the table tbl_kaf_my-topic already in the DB. with the columns : 
PID -varchar(4000) PK; 
messageId -varchar(4000); 
value -varchar(4000)

Comment: I started the consumer without creating the table but no table got generated and nothing appears in logs either.

Comment: Any Updates from anyone?